# How many total orders consistent with a partial order?

Tags: combinatorics, measure-theory, order-theory

I have a finite set of objects $X$, whose power set is partially ordered by $\subseteq$.

1. Consider all possible *total orderings* of the power set $\mathscr{P}(X)$ which are compatible with the partial order $\subseteq$ in the sense that $A \subsetneq B \Rightarrow A \prec B$. How many compatible total orders are there?
2. Some orders $\prec$ have the special property that they can be concretely quantified by assigning numerical weights to each element in the set; then a subset has a smaller total weight than another subset if and only if the subsets are related by $\prec$.

   Specifically, this means that you can find a weight assignment function $f:\mathscr{P}(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ such that every subset's weight is the sum of its elements' weights: $$\forall S\subseteq X,\quad f(S) = \sum_{x\in S} f(\{x\})$$
   and the weight respects order in that $f(S) < f(T) \iff S \prec T.$

   How many *quantifiable* total orders are there?  (For my applications, I'm interested in weight assignments where $f(S) = 0 \iff S = \varnothing$.)

Comment: What do you mean "compatible with"?

Comment: I guess $A\subsetneq B \implies A \prec B$.

Comment: A possibly-interesting "between" class of orders are the total orders where if $S\prec T$ then $T^{c}\prec S^{c}$.

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti Yes, that's right. I've adjusted my question to clarify that.

Comment: @bof I originally thought I meant something about being non-isomorphic but now I think I mean just not identical. I've nixed the wording.

Comment: The answer to the first question is OEIS sequence  
[A046873](http://oeis.org/A046873), "Number of total orders extending inclusion on $P(\{1,\dots,n\})$."

Answer (score 0):

To question 2:

These are called *coherent Boolean term orders* by MacLagan (1999).

> **Definition 2.4.** A Boolean term order is *coherent* if there is a weight vector $w = (w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n) \in \mathbb N^n$ such that
> $$ \alpha \prec \beta \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i\in\alpha}w_i < \sum_{j\in\beta}w_j.$$

MacLagan uses integer weights, but it would not seem to make a difference; if you can assign positive real weights that quantify a total order, then you can just scale them up so that every pair of sets has weight difference of more than $1$, then round them down to integers, and the order is unchanged.

MacLagan counted them up to $n=|X|=7$ and the counts are in OEIS [A009997](https://oeis.org/A009997):
$$1, 1, 2, 14, 516, 124187, 214580603$$
The numbers in this sequence have been divided by $n!$ to account for the (somehow trivial) factor of $n!$ that ensues from permuting the $n$ elements of $X$. If you want to count such orders as distinct, just multiply the numbers by $n!$.

- *MacLagan, Diane*, [**Boolean term orders and the root system $B_n$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1006207716298), Order 15, No. 3, 279-295 (1999). [ZBL0932.05093](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0932.05093).